# Double every even integer in a list

Tags: python, list

I am working on doubling every even integer element from list 'a' and then storing the results back in 'a'. The list 'a' is a list of integers. So far:

```
def double(item):
    if [x for x in item]%2 == 0:
        return [x * 2 for x in item]
    else:
        return [x in item]
```

give me this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

How can I turn this list into an int?

Comment: Is the argument as list of lists or a list of integers?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You should learn Python basics first.

Comment: it's a list of integers! sorry about the confusion

Comment: Have you tried doing a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems:

1. Your conditional (`if`) should be applied to each element of `item` inside a `for` loop (or list comprehension).
2. You have the module operator (`%`) that is being applied to a list.
3. `[x * 2 for x in item]` - this branch will create a list for every number in item.
4. `[x in item]` checks to see if the value of `x` is in `item`. So it will result in either `[True]` or `[False]`.

Code:

```
def double(item):
    return [x if x % 2 else x * 2 for x in item]
```